# Blazor - how do I get rid of a parameter value?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a component that I want to be able to navigate to with 2 different parameters:

@page "/node/{nid:guid}"
@page "/node/{nid:guid}/create/{fid:guid}"

nid is the id of a node in a tree, fid the type of node to create under the parent. Both are GUID's and properly encoded.

I call /node/nid and it works.
I call /node/nid/create/fid and it works

Now back: /node/nid

I then navigate to /node/nid and the value of fid is still there. It does not matter that I ret the value in OnParamtersSetAsync - it seemsd that once the value has onece been called in, it is always set again in SetParametersAsync. I tried deleting it in there, it still gets set again. It is always in the collection. On every call coming, I see that value in the fame.

What is the process of not having this parameter set over and over again? There seems to be no method to get rid of that attribute in the frame that is obvious and - somehow - the use of multiple URL's to indicate like this looks standard to me.

Adding Relevant Code:

- Page:
  @page "/node/{NodeIdentifier:guid}"
  @page "/node/{NodeIdentifier:guid}/create/{FunctionIdentifier:guid}"
- Code behind:
  [Parameter]
  public Guid NodeIdentifier { get; set; }

  [Parameter]
  public Guid FunctionIdentifier { get; set; }
- Navigation calls:
  NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"/node/{parentNodeIdentifier}/create/{functionIdentifier}");
  NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"/node/{identifier}");

Use the first navigate to, THEN the 2nd - the functionIdentifier is never cleared.

Comment: Can you shoe the relevant code in your component?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, so yes: provide details. Best is a [mre]

Comment: Added code snippets.

Comment: Still no repro. Write up a proper [mre] or it just didn't happen. Verify the mre before posting.